# Django: Having problem when calculate differences between today's date and date in database

Tags: django

I have an object name Device with 'trandate' attribute.

I want to get differences between today's date and database date.

And then calculate the number of devices where the device's inactive_days is greater than 31.

Here is my code.

```
todays_date = datetime.now()
trandate = request.GET.get('devc_trandate')
inactive_days = todays_date - datetime(trandate)
inactive_devices = Cust.objects.values('name').annotate(inact_devc_count = Count('devc',filter=Q(inactive_days__gte=31)))
```

But I got an error.

```
an integer is required (got type NoneType)
```

Traceback:

```
File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  124.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\customers\views.py" in DevSummary_more
  178.     inactive_days = todays_date - datetime(trandate)

Exception Type: TypeError at /summary/more/
Exception Value: an integer is required (got type NoneType)
```

Comment: can you please share your full traceback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error shows that the `'devc_trandate'` is None.

There is another way to do this:

```
todays_date = datetime.now()
inactive_date = todays_date - timedelta(days=31)
inactive_devices = Cust.objects.values('name').annotate(inact_devc_count = Count('devc',filter=Q(devc__trandate__lt=inactive_date)))
```

Since you want to get the number of devices where the device's inactive_days is greater than 31, you can do `today - 31` to get the date, then you can get the inactive device by checking which trandate is lesser than the inactive date.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is no `'devc_trandate'` parameter in the request. So when creating datatime instance its getting `None` giving you that error.

Also to create datatime object you need at least 3 parameter for year, month and day. Don't think you can pass string representation of datetime to create an object. You may want to use `strptime()` method to parse string into datetime object.